# Nexus 6p won't charge on included charger

Tags: charging, nexus-6p

Not sure what to make of this one.  I have two nexus 6P's.

1. Phone A won't charge on included charger+cable+outlet, however it does charge on a variety of other chargers I have access to.
2. Phone B charges on the same charger+cable+outlet Phone A won't charge on

Any ideas as to what's wrong and how to resolve?

**Edit:** From comments *Both phones charging on the same setup (charger/cable/outlet).*

Comment: You have left out information on USB cable. When you say charger, do you mean "charger+ USB cable" or just the charger. It makes a difference. Please edit your question to clarify

Comment: Also are you charging both phones from same point charging point or Dodger points? If different, it could be a charging point problem

Comment: Both phones charging on the same setup (charger/cable/outlet).

Answer (score 0):

The uncooperative phone started charging again on the included charger setup after a reboot.